# What is a semantic cognitive map?

Tags: terminology

Based on: J. P. Carvalho, "On the Semantics and the Use of Fuzzy Cognitive Maps in Social Sciences" (WCCI, 2010 -- [PDF](http://www.inesc-id.pt/pt/indicadores/Ficheiros/6431.pdf)) and Richard Dagan's web page [Cognitive Mapping](http://richarddagan.com/cogmap.php).

A cognitive map consists of nodes representing concepts and ties indicating relationship between the concepts. 
In Carvalho section IV, the semantics is used in perspective of the presented model. Dagan's definition of semantic map is that it is a tree like structure branching from a main concept.

Also, the answer https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9800/are-semantic-networks-ontologies?rq=1 further adds to my confusion as to what is the significant different between cognitive map where nodes are concepts and semantic map where also the nodes are concepts.

I am unable to find significant difference between concept map and semantic map. Can somebody please explain in simple language? Thank you